# Get the ID of this from an onClick(this) in a button?

Tags: javascript

Sorry Copy Paste error, the functions now match

I have some simple code and I cannot seem to get the id of the clicked item?

```
<input type="button" name="remove_grouping" value=Remove Group" onClick="removeGrouping(this);"/>';
```

Then a simple JS Function

```
function removeGrouping(src)
{
alert(src.id);
}
```

Comment: You're calling `removeRow` but the function you posted is called `removeGrouping`

Comment: Since you don't have an ID, exactly which attribute value are you really trying to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you add the ID parameter in the IMG?

```
<img id="some-id" onclick="removeRow(this)" src="someimage">
```

And also you are calling a different function in the onclick.